# Tizen WEB applications are not working in version 2.2

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I'm new to Tizen and started development by setting the SDK version as 2.2 in a 64-bit Windows 7 machine.

I created a new WEB app and while trying to run it (on emulator and a real device) nothing is happening after the installation. I tried several times to launch the application, but its not launching (in emulator, a black screen is appearing).

There is no problems with the NATIVE applications. Sample Native applications are running without any issue in both emulator and device.

The device details are as follows:

> Ref.Device-PQ
>
> TIZEN 2.2.0 (Tizen_Ref.Device-PQ_20130719.1629)

While trying to launch the application I'm getting the error log as follows:

```
09-23 14:09:24.465 : ERROR / Tizen::Base::Collection ( 2709 : 2709 ) : virtual result Tizen::Base::Collection::ArrayList::IndexOf(const Tizen::Base::Object&, int, int, int&) const(290) > [E_OBJ_NOT_FOUND] The arraylist is empty.
09-23 14:09:24.465 : ERROR / Tizen::Base::Collection ( 2709 : 2709 ) : virtual result Tizen::Base::Collection::ArrayList::Remove(const Tizen::Base::Object&)(393) > [E_OBJ_NOT_FOUND] Propagating.
09-23 14:09:24.465 : ERROR / Tizen::Base::Collection ( 2709 : 2709 ) : virtual result Tizen::Base::Collection::ArrayList::IndexOf(const Tizen::Base::Object&, int, int, int&) const(290) > [E_OBJ_NOT_FOUND] The arraylist is empty.
09-23 14:09:24.465 : ERROR / Tizen::Base::Collection ( 2709 : 2709 ) : virtual result Tizen::Base::Collection::ArrayList::Remove(const Tizen::Base::Object&)(393) > [E_OBJ_NOT_FOUND] Propagating.
09-23 14:09:24.465 : ERROR / Tizen::App ( 2709 : 2709 ) : virtual void Tizen::App::_ContextManager::OnApplicationTerminated(const Tizen::App::AppId&, int)(477) > Not registered pid(3560)
```

Please give some light on the issue which I'm facing with WEB apps, Whether I need to make any additional settings to run WEB applications in Tizen 2.2.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In tizen device 2.2 After flashing you will get an error `OpenGL is not enabled`,so some web apps will not run in device.
We need to enable 3D acceleration.

Steps to enable 3D acceleration :

Download mali DDK from :

> https://source.tizen.org/mali-ddk-2.2

We install Mali DDK through Smart Development Bridge (I tried with `ubanthu 12.04`)

In command prompt go to `cd /tizen-sdk/tools/`

```
   # sdb -d push libtbm-*.rpm /home/
   # sdb -d push libump-*.rpm /home/
   # sdb -d push opengl-es-*.rpm /home/
   # sdb -d shell
```

Run these commands and after that ;

```
  # cd /home/
  # rpm -e --nodeps opengl-es-virtual-drv
  # rpm -ivh --force *.rpm
  # sync
  # reboot
```

Now 3D acceleration got enabled in your device.

After these steps you can run any web app on tizen device 2.2.

Comment: Hmm.. Seems like this solution may work for me. Give me some time to try this in the device. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Current version of emulator does not support web apps of sdk version 2.2. so you will get error with package id and your web app will not be launched.

However,to test your web app, you can try remote test lab...
you can visit following link, and test your web app in this devices.

http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action#

and yes you can always run your webapp in web simulator provided with tizen ide.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to load this URL. The page says 'the requested URL is no longer available'. And not only in the emulator, also in Device I'm unable to launch the web app. Web simulator is working well.

Comment: Okay. Now Both links are working. Let me try these Remote Test Devices. Thanks.
Any idea about the problem with Tizen real devices. I given the logs. WEB applications are still not working in the specified device.

Answer (score 1):

Native and web applications (widgets) run in different environments. Web applications run in the Web Runtime and native run without the Web Runtime.

From the errors you just posted it seems that you run in fact one of your native project, to be sure that you don't run other projects from the Workspace just close/save every other project and leave open only the one you want to deploy.

Just let me know if things change and if you still experience problems.

Comment: Followed steps as U mentioned. But still no success. After successful installation, WEB applications are not launching in emulator and device.

Comment: @Midhu Have you tried to run it in the Web Simulator instead of the emulator?

Comment: Yes, in web simulator it is working fine. Problem is when trying to use emulator or device.

Comment: @Midhu Sometimes one machine in the emulator goes wrong due to various reasons, have you tried to create a new device.

Comment: Yeah.. I tried with a number of emulators in different machines. I noticed that emulator created in a linux machine is working fine. Problem is with Emulators on Windows7-64bit machines and the specified device. (I only have one real device with me)

Comment: @Midhu If you have the same SDK version and on the other operating systems is working fine there might be a bug or something. Here you can find the tizen bugtracker:  https://bugs.tizen.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa