# Tizen WEB applications are not working

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

Please tell me why when I click on the application in the emulator, nothing happens?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSvaS.png

Log:

```
11-03 17:09:06.259 : ERROR / Tizen::Base::Collection ( 2165 : 2165 ) : virtual result Tizen::Base::Collection::ArrayList::IndexOf(const Tizen::Base::Object&, int, int, int&) const(290) > [E_OBJ_NOT_FOUND] The arraylist is empty.

11-03 17:09:06.259 : ERROR / Tizen::Base::Collection ( 2165 : 2165 ) : virtual result Tizen::Base::Collection::ArrayList::Remove(const Tizen::Base::Object&)(393) > [E_OBJ_NOT_FOUND] Propagating.

11-03 17:09:06.259 : ERROR / Tizen::Base::Collection ( 2165 : 2165 ) : virtual result Tizen::Base::Collection::ArrayList::IndexOf(const Tizen::Base::Object&, int, int, int&) const(290) > [E_OBJ_NOT_FOUND] The arraylist is empty.
11-03 17:09:06.259 : ERROR / Tizen::Base::Collection ( 2165 : 2165 ) : virtual result Tizen::Base::Collection::ArrayList::Remove(const Tizen::Base::Object&)(393) > [E_OBJ_NOT_FOUND] Propagating.
11-03 17:09:06.279 : ERROR / Tizen::App ( 2165 : 2165 ) : virtual void Tizen::App::_ContextManager::OnApplicationTerminated(const Tizen::App::AppId&, int)(477) > Not registered pid(2482)
```

I found it
[Tizen WEB applications are not working in version 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952186/tizen-web-applications-are-not-working-in-version-2-2)
but I do not know how to do this on os x mavericks

and I do not think this is the issue, since it does not run even the most simple applications

Comment: You can test your App on the Samsung Remote Test Lab: http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/

Comment: Have you tried the newer version?